# TypeScript: Is it possible to restrict arrow function parameter return type?

Tags: typescript

I have a typescript function that accepts two params, a config `object` and a `function`:

```js
function executeMaybe<Input, Output> (
  config: { percent: number },
  fn: (i: Input) => Output
): (i: Input) => Output | 'maybe next time ' {

  return function(input: Input) {
    return Math.random() < config.percent / 100 
      ? fn(input)
      : 'maybe next time ';
  };
}
```

Usage of the function looks like this:

```js
interface Foo { number: number; }
interface Bar { string: string; }

const makeBarMaybe = executeMaybe<Foo, Bar>(
  { percent: 75 },
  foo => ({ string: `derived from Foo: ${JSON.stringify(foo)}` })
);
```

If I attempt to add a nonexistent property to my config object literal, TypeScript kindly informs me:

> Argument of type '{ percent: number; baz: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ percent: number; }'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'baz' does not exist in type '{ percent: number; }'. (2345)

However, when I add an additional property to the object returned from the function param, no error is mentioned:

[image: screenshot]

**Is it possible to have TS provide an error in this scenario without explicitly providing the function's return type?**

[image: another screenshot]

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-raqxht?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100) where I was playing around with this.

Comment: What do you mean by "unknown property"?

Comment: Sorry, I just mean a property that doesn't exist on the type.

Comment: How is the `executeMaybe` function defined?

Comment: Your code looks good. I don't understand why it doesn't report the error neither. It looks like a legit Ts bug to me .

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks

Answer (score 1):

You see this error because of [excess-property-checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks). Literal objects are treated in a differen way.

> Object literals get special treatment and undergo excess property checking when assigning them to other variables, or passing them as arguments. If an object literal has any properties that the “target type” doesn’t have, you’ll get an error:

If you still want to add more extra properties to your argument, you should expect a subtype of `Foo` instead of super type. I mean, that your argument should `extend` `Foo` instead of being `Foo`.

You need to rewrite your `executeMaybe` and apply a constraint where `callback` function expects subtype of `Input` instead of `Input` itself:

```js
function executeMaybe<Input, Output>(
  config: { percent: number },
  fn: <Inp extends Input>(i: Inp) => Output
): <Inp extends Input>(i: Inp) => Output | 'maybe next time ' {
  return function (input: Input) {
    const result =
      Math.random() < config.percent / 100 ? fn(input) : 'maybe next time ';

    console.log(result);

    return result;
  };
}
```

WHole code:

```js
function executeMaybe<Input, Output>(
  config: { percent: number },
  fn: <Inp extends Input>(i: Inp) => Output
): <Inp extends Input>(i: Inp) => Output | 'maybe next time ' {
  return function (input: Input) {
    const result =
      Math.random() < config.percent / 100 ? fn(input) : 'maybe next time ';

    console.log(result);

    return result;
  };
}

console.clear();

interface Foo {
  number: number;
}

interface Bar {
  string: string;
}

const makeBarMaybe = executeMaybe<Foo, Bar>({ percent: 75 }, (foo) => ({
  string: `derived from Foo: ${JSON.stringify(foo)}`,
}));

const explicitFoo: Foo = { number: 10 };
const implicitFoo = { number: 20 };
const superFoo = { number: 30, extra: 'super' };

makeBarMaybe(explicitFoo);
makeBarMaybe(implicitFoo);
makeBarMaybe(superFoo); // same object | duck typing allows
makeBarMaybe({ number: 30, extra: 'super' }); // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB7IiKyCyBDATwCNkAeASTAAcsAaRAeSxqgD4AKAKEUQgWBgBzAFyIA3oirIAThGRgoosCAC2JaYgC%20tbomBhRFailTYwAEwDOiSiw4xRtgJSIAvK0bMsnJ4dsmzKxtqLHtHahd3TygWRAAfRAByFUISRDA0KERYFWREQF4NwGw9xPFdaWQoEGkkUEhYBER2GBDFYJYXMV0ePjBLLPLLEAAbLNcunkR8KAALADppPAs4FXYXUl5%20IVmpWXksgHpEAEYABhPEAH49MCaWl1Fk1LyM02yYXILigG5OcZ7LOBDZCzIZwQTsAbDKBOH7jcqVaqISEjH48TQ-TS-f6A4EQIF4aSrWHNbDSYB4OSIABicDgpR4yjUMiUqnUGN%20JJk5MpACECfTEH1pM0RIKoMKwIJ2Zx-lkUgBrZB86T4Yh5VwmDBYXBPUg0uD0ZUcCQ7OQKUQAdgArFp6OxgLTIh52J0eEKRaIAAbmGQwABuyHMemky2ptNEABIxAApADKDAAcrN3ZKYMACPbHZpPTpNE4YViEH0TFQhjAIDAoPrRPq3OJ0qzmcdzuiZUWsu9S%20XK7WNRJGepRAAmFs-WWCkA7Xv1gdNgDMJ3omQWD0GOxKrc4CqVBNVJHYaC7Farjp%202%20Ve%20QTRUR57p63eEVF6e7DXMn1MMQ%200OljwHzgRAAFYYFkCTmCAEDytkBBUCKiB4EMoIAO6WA%20T67i%20-aNtIogLkupgrkkb7SBun7fogcDykAA)

**UPDATE**

My bad, probably did not understand the question.

TypeScript does not support exact types, but there is a workaround:

```js
type PseudoExact<T, U> = T extends U ? U extends T ? U : never : never

function executeMaybe<Input, Output>(
  config: { percent: number },
  fn: <Inp extends Input>(i: PseudoExact<Input, Inp>) => Output
): <Inp extends Input>(i: PseudoExact<Input, Inp>) => Output | 'maybe next time ' {
  return function <Inp extends Input>(input: PseudoExact<Input, Inp>) {
    const result =
      Math.random() < config.percent / 100 ? fn(input) : 'maybe next time ';

    console.log(result);

    return result;
  };
}
```

**`PseudoExact`** - checks whether supertype extends subtype.

WHole code with expected errors:

```js
type PseudoExact<T, U> = T extends U ? U extends T ? U : never : never

function executeMaybe<Input, Output>(
  config: { percent: number },
  fn: <Inp extends Input>(i: PseudoExact<Input, Inp>) => Output
): <Inp extends Input>(i: PseudoExact<Input, Inp>) => Output | 'maybe next time ' {
  return function <Inp extends Input>(input: PseudoExact<Input, Inp>) {
    const result =
      Math.random() < config.percent / 100 ? fn(input) : 'maybe next time ';

    console.log(result);

    return result;
  };
}

console.clear();

interface Foo {
  number: number;
}

interface Bar {
  string: string;
}

const makeBarMaybe = executeMaybe<Foo, Bar>({ percent: 75 }, (foo) => ({
  string: `derived from Foo: ${JSON.stringify(foo)}`,
}));

const explicitFoo: Foo = { number: 10 };
const implicitFoo = { number: 20 };
const superFoo = { number: 30, extra: 'super' };

makeBarMaybe(explicitFoo);
makeBarMaybe(implicitFoo);
makeBarMaybe(superFoo); // expected error
makeBarMaybe({ number: 30, extra: 'super' }); // expected error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgzhArgEwPYFEAeBDAxsAHgBUAaKAVQD4oBeKIqCTYCAO2TgqgH4umX2nBr3JQAXFFYQAbhABO4yTPkAoFQDNErfAEtUrRpgi5ELALLYQAIwgEAkqzCmyAeVNPglABQqoUXPrqOgDmEgDeUJByuGzAEqyIALY2CgC%20JL5Q6qwS9o6GAhxQDh7eOhLwSGhYeIQlzsWOlACUtNRuwB4qzbklBWxF9Z5e5bAIKBg4%20HkeZCUtbVAdHlAAPlAA5ImWNkrMUMA6idCAvBuA2HsbUGGZchDAiHIGmtqH%20lAz-YKNpSOOphXjapTOp-YBzJqta5%20PwBVhwYBQW5wRAAGwRNEy0KgFmAAAsAHRybDsVCJLytAj%20QIhfFRGKsBEAeigAEYAAxsnhZVi-DytCRbHbQKT7Q7HKDnDYAbjUWNhcFQKIg%20JRqGCXiRqOAzRlmMRdweBk1aJlflSMtSanliuVuCV2Dk5N1OgZ8nUeGgADFUKgrpkEsl5PEkikLWoXSw5O6YlAAEIOv1%20eFyF2hKDJ1NhlTyhHbADWEHjcgs1mgdCYxlMEBLNgI3tQZCL3gidNiEgA7ABWKDpKBedQ%201o0aheKHp4Ap1hpgAGyHkOlkyCyclJUHrEgAJGEAFIAZRcADl8Rmpzp1CB%204PUtOMqlmjqrfp4YYwCidLgdMB12ufbQrpIQyDVlOXNbMnwRI5X3fT96z-CIAxSCQACYQJlHN00QKJYLoeDALkCQAGY2TIfgiQFZEokuUCVHzQsHRrCAvCYKCPy-QcZVoosGJGRIWJg9iaOwAsuKFLwKPkesdSgRlmWY4wWCXeQVzkQThPo0TcMDfCoCIkjmDIzZxLkKipJkl95IgRS5GUoA)

Instead of my naive `PseudoExact` you can use more advanced type utility. Please see [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27024#issuecomment-421529650)

```js
export type Equals<X, Y> =
    (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends
    (<T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2) ? true : false;
```

Comment: "*If you still want to add more extra properties to your argument...*" - I was not wanting to allow providing additional properties, but rather catch errors due to typos in property names.  Is there any way to get those `excess-property-checks` applied to the object literal that's defined as the return value of the function param?

Comment: [Playground](https://shorturl.at/nquJ2)

Comment: @BizzyBob made an update